# How can I output the safepoint log in a specified file？

Tags: java-8, jvm

I am using java8 and I did set JVM argument to set GC log path，but the safepoint log did not output to the specified file and they still in my console output.What should i do to let the safepoint-log output to a file just like GC log？

Comment: if I am not missing it you need `-XX:+LogVMOutput` and `-XX:LogFile=some-path`; though in jdk-9 this is much easier.

Answer (score 2):

In java-8 you need two flags : `-XX:+LogVMOutput` ( internally a safepoint is refered as `vmop` as in "vm operation", that is why the weird flag name, I guess ). To redirect the output to a file you need `-XX:LogFile=path`.

Since java-9, there is "unified logging" that makes this far more easy and intuitive, IMO. For example:

```
-Xlog:safepoint*=debug:file=safepoint.log
```